# How to produce this vocal effect?

Tags: mixing, vocals

How do you create the vocal effect done in this video at 2:19

, the "urban" part?

Comment: Isn't that just mumbling with rhythm?

Comment: yeah but seemed some effects to carry it out

Comment: Maybe some notch EQ to narrow the spectrum outside of 1-3k and Compression to bring up the volume of the mumbling. Give that a try. See if that gives you the effect you are looking for.

Comment: No effects at all. He is just mumbling lol.... Sure with any recording there is some basic mixing going on, but there is really nothing special going on here.